# Slowdown with recursive function using vectors

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm running this function around 30 times per frame and experiencing massive slow down. This function is the cause of it, any ideas why?

```
bool Pathfinding::takeStep(
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>* vec, int px, int py, int sx, int sy, int r)
{
    if (px == sx && py == sy) return true;  // destination reached
    bool clear = true;
    // step up
    if ((*vec)[px][py - 1] == -1)  // location not tested yet
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < r * 2; ++i)
        {
            int tx = px - r + i;
            int ty = py - r - 1;
            // Make sure test coordinates are on the grid
            if (tx > 0 && ty > 0 && tx < width && ty < height)
            {
                // already stuck
                if (grid[tx][ty] == 1) clear = false;
            }
            else
                clear = false;  // not on grid
        }
        if (clear)
        {
            // keep moving
            (*vec)[px][py - 1] = (*vec)[px][py] + 1;
            // add one to step count and confirm this way is clear
            if (takeStep(vec, px, py - 1, sx, sy, r)) return true;
        }
        else
        {
            (*vec)[px][py - 1] = -2;  // mark as already tried
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What values do you pass in when you call it? Specifically `py` and `sy`, which together seem to determine the recursion depth. And `r`, which determines the amount of looping done.

Comment: Try to add some sort of counter to this function to see how may times it's actually called per frame.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've gone through it using break points and it's just under 30 times per frame.

Comment: @Cameron I pass in these values    if (takeStep(stepp, ex, ey, sx, sy, rad))

Comment: @Sean: I meant the actual numeric values at runtime. How are we supposed to help you figure out what's happening if you don't provide any figures? It's like asking 'Why is my muffin recipe taking 6 hours to make?' and posting a recipe that calls for `X cups of flour and y pounds of butter' -- we can't magically guess what values you've chosen for x and y!

Comment: Okay, I assumed it didn't really matter since they are ints. ex = 325, ey = 250, sx = 325, sy = 220, rad = 12. step is pointer to vector of[640][480]